# What specifically does the SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE flag in SDL_CreateRenderer do?

Tags: sdl-2

In https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_RendererFlags it says:

> the renderer is a software fallback

What does this mean? That if SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE flag is on, and there is no GPU, that instead of the renderer creation failing, the rendering will be done on the CPU?

That if this flag is on, and SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED is off, that the CPU will be used for rendering, despite there being a GPU?

I really can't find any answer to this question anywhere. I have even tried reading the source code.

I need to know this in order to be able to decide which flags I want. The current explanation doesn't really parse.

Quick links:

- https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_CreateRenderer
- https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL (src and include are folders with the actual functions and stuff)

Comment: The point of using a `SDL_Renderer` is to create and use a hardware accelerated rendering context. If, for some reason, SDL cannot provide one for you it will give you a software rendering context instead. The benefit of this is to provide the same rendering API whether it’s hardware accelerated or not. This flag will not do anything unless a hardware accelerated rendering context cannot be provided.

Comment: [`SDL_CreateRenderer()`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.28.5/src/render/SDL_render.c#L936) searches [the list of compiled-in renderers](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.28.5/src/render/SDL_render.c#L92-L131) down [here](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.28.5/src/render/SDL_render.c#L989-L1002).